# Calling SHA256 with ECDSA algorithm from a Karate script

Tags: javascript, karate, sha256, ecdsa

I am using KARATE with the standalone JAR, version 0.9.5.RC5.
Inside a Karate scenario, I have to sign a string with a private key, using the SHA256 with ECDSA algorithm, in base64.
I need this signature further in a request.
So, I have written in the scenario :

```
* def stringtobesigned = 'mystringtosign'
* def privkey = 'DeIHYzu9...'
* def Signature = call read('sha256ECDSA.js')
```

And in the sha256ECDSA.js file, I have written :

```
function fn() {
    var mykey = karate.get('privkey');
    var strToBeSigned = karate.get('idstring2signed');
    ...
    return signValue;
    }
```

Can anybody tell me how to implement this algorithm in my use case?
I need to replace '...' with the right code, to the value 'signValue'.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is not really a karate question and is simply "how to do this in Java" and then you plug in as you already know how to do. so refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25261823/143475

Comment: In my sha256ECDSA.js file, I want to use the jsrsasign javascript Library (wich provides the SHA256 with ECDSA encryption), with this first line : var r = require('jsrsasign');  But it doesn't work because require uses Node.js. So, how to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100077/143475

Comment: Ok… you have written : "My suggestion is you should find a Java library that does what "faker" does and integrate it.". Is it possible with the Karate standalone JAR too ?

Comment: yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56458094/143475